# React native jsx in a nested map

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, map-function

Need help with nested maps. Pretty confusing to figure out

```
      {
        sectorHeader.map((dutyPeriod) => (
          <Text style={Styles.heading} />
          dutyPeriod.dutyItems.map((dutyItem) => (
            <SectorCell
             flightNumber={`${dutyItem.flightLeg.scheduledFlightDesignator.airlineCode}${dutyItem.flightLeg.scheduledFlightDesignator.flightNumber}`}
             flightDate={dutyItem.flightLeg.departureTimes.scheduled.localTime}
            />
        ))))
      }
```

I get an error in the line "dutyPeriod.dutyItems.map((dutyItem) => (" because of the jsx in the previous line. How can i have a jsx when i have multiple maps?

Error that I get

```
Unexpected token, expected ,

{sectorHeader.map((dutyPeriod) => (
  <Text style={Styles.heading} />
   dutyPeriod.dutyItems.map((dutyItem) => (
   ^
```

Comment: please mention the exact error message that you are getting.

Comment: I have just updated the post.

Comment: As I know, If you use react 16.0 and don't have 'extra element' you need to type a comma between your components

Comment: amage : there is no way i can add a comma in the above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

surround js codes with {} in jsx codes:

```
{
dutyPeriod.dutyItems.map((dutyItem) => (
        <SectorCell
         flightNumber={`${dutyItem.flightLeg.scheduledFlightDesignator.airlineCode}${dutyItem.flightLeg.scheduledFlightDesignator.flightNumber}`}
         flightDate={dutyItem.flightLeg.departureTimes.scheduled.localTime}
        />
    ))
}
```